# ¿Cómo empujar un elemento hacia abajo automáticamente utilizando mat-accordion?

Tags: css, html5, angular, css3

Quisiera saber como empujar hacia abajo un elemento de forma natural automáticamente con css (adjunto imagen sobre lo que sucede). En la imagen se muestra a los elementos del mat-expansion-panel sobrepasar el footer y quisiera que sólo mande para abajo el footer con un padding-bottom.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo como framework javascript Angular 9, gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál elemento es el que deseas mover?, además ¿podrías por favor agregar lo que llevas?, lee [ask]

Comment: Mover hacia abajo el footer

Comment: Sin código para que tengamos un ejemplo mínimo y verificable poco podemos hacer, por favor lee [ask]